# can't get the global variable to work on a function

Tags: php, forms, function, variables, global

I am trying to create a global variable that can be applied and call to any php file but I cannot display the output value of the declared global variable. This is an exact example of what I need to know of how:

testglobal.php

```
<?php
session_start(); 
error_reporting(0);
?>
<html>
<head><title>Sum with Public Function</title></head>
<body>
<form action="output.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="a">
<input type="text" name="b">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body></html>


<?php
echo "";

$sums=$_POST['sums'];


if($sums){
global $d,$e,$c;
include('global-function.php');
get_instance();
$c=$d+$e;
}


?>
```

global-function.php

```
<?php

function get_instance(){

    $d = $_POST['a'];
    $e  = $_POST['b'];

}    


?>
```

-and-

output.php

```
    <?php
global $d,$e,$c;
include('global-function.php');
get_instance();
echo "The First Number is: ".$d."<br />";
echo "The Second Number is: ".$e."<br />";
$c = $d + $e;
echo "The Sum is: ".$c;
?>
```

The testglobal.php will display the form.
The global-function.php will store the value of $_post into the global variable.
The output.php will process and display whatever the value stored in the global variable.

Thanks in advance for the help...

Comment: You need to declare your globals inside your function

Comment: If you want to spot a error change: `error_reporting(0);` to : `ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: So you want to use globals  in a function to assign super-globals to these globals?! You should not do that as you will have no idea what happens where when your code-base grows and / or you need to debug. Just send the values you need to use as parameters and have the function return the values you want to assign.

Comment: For one thing, you don't have a form element named "sums".

Comment: @jeroen I see your point... basically I need to use super-globals that is because I will be leaning into three different primary key in the code for searching record and passing the record to all the forms at one time... am working on a system that will be working that way and to hide users to see what is record parsing within the code and pages

Comment: @user4484940 You've lost me...

Comment: @fred actually I just mistype the name in the sums in the form but it is the button.... All are working great now... Thanks for all your bright ideas guys!

Comment: @jeroen... actually it a form in a single php file that is calling globals and all the subsystems php pages will call the single php file from different areas and different department all at one time... so super-global is needed for this to work but I do really appreciate your suggestion and I have also used that for years but not the super-globals so am really new to super-globals. My only point is how to grab values of data from globals to apply in different pages of my subsystems leaning to a single form that is global

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya My concern was mainly with the use of the function, not with the global scope of the `$d` and `$e` variables. The problem is that you have a function that requires input and needs to set / change these variables but it doesn't receive input nor return anything. That makes trouble-shooting and testing very hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare your global variables inside your function

```
function get_instance(){

        global $d , $e ;

        $d = $_POST['a'];
        $e  = $_POST['b'];

    }
```

Comment: Thanks! it is working now... I remove the global in the testglobal.php then edit the global-function with what you suggested and it is now working.... Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @jeroen  do you have any suggestion or a better way ? please share your answer

Comment: @user4484940 Great , please make the answer as the accepted one , so the future users can easily get help